# Function that returns a list of cars

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

As part of my homework it is required to write a function that returns a list of cars, i.e. the function searches for cars where the search string is one of the car models and the search is case insensitive.

```
def search_by_model(all_cars: str, model: str) -> list:
    if not all_cars or not model:
        return []
    all_makes = []
    cars = all_cars.split(",")
    for car in cars:
        unique_car = car.split(" ")
        if model.lower() == unique_car[1].lower():
            all_makes.append(" ".join(unique_car[0:]))
    return all_makes
```

So, in my case `print(search_by_model("Audi A4,Audi a4 2021,Audi A40", "A4"))` yields `['Audi A4', 'Audi a4 2021']`, which is OK. However, I don't understand how to do the same but with two or more words, for example, if I want the "a4 2021" model, then I should only get "Audi a4 2021".

Task description:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check that [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) the words in `model` are in `unique_car`:

```py
def search_by_model(all_cars: str, model: str) -> list:
    if not all_cars or not model:
        return []
    all_makes = []
    cars = all_cars.split(",")
    model = model.lower().split(" ")
    for car in cars:
        unique_car = car.split(" ")
        if all(mdl in map(str.lower, unique_car) for mdl in model):
            all_makes.append(" ".join(unique_car))
    return all_makes

print(search_by_model("Audi A4,Audi a4 2021,Audi A40", "A4"))
# ['Audi A4', 'Audi a4 2021']
print(search_by_model("Audi A4,Audi a4 2021,Audi A40", "A4 2021"))
# ['Audi a4 2021']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in your case the function returns the list in small letters, but is it possible to make it return list as it was in the print? Not audi a4, but Audi A4.

Comment: @Cornifer sorry about that, I've updated the code

Comment: oh and one more question, if I want no duplicates, can I just use if unique_car[1] not in all_makes: ... or is there some more elegant solution?

Comment: @Cornifer yeah, you could do `if all(...) and " ".join(unique_car) not in all_makes` or alternatively `return list(set(all_makes))`

Comment: sorry to bother you, tester says that there are two problems, one of them was that the first word should be ignored, I solved it by simply adding ```if all(model in map(str.lower, unique_car) for model in model) and unique_car[0 ].lower() != model[0].lower():``` and the second one says "no match when searching multiple words AssertionError: assert ['Audi A4 2021'] == []". I don't quite understand what could be wrong here, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Cornifer not sure what you mean by "the first word should be ignored", do you mean the first word in the strings in `all_cars`, or in `model`?

Comment: by the first word i mean the make of the car i.e. ```print(search_by_model("Audi A4,Audi a4 2021,Audi A40", "Audi A4"))``` should return ```[]```, not ```['Audi A4', 'Audi a4 2021']```.

Comment: @Cornifer just make this change: `if all(mdl in map(str.lower, unique_car[1:]) for mdl in model):`

Comment: @Cornifer do you know what the call to `search_by_model` was that gave that error?

Comment: nope, the tester is not mine (i just sent my work to gitlab using pycharm). The only thing I can assume is that if ```print(search_by_model('Audi A4 2021'))```, then it should return ```[]```, but this function takes only two arguments.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to a description of the specification of the problem? Maybe if I read that I might get an insight...

Comment: Judging from the descrpition, it looks like you should return *no* matches at all if the search string has multiple words. And I don't see anything that says the search result for `Audi` should be empty (was that elsewhere?). So you probably want something like https://ideone.com/lW2pio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248496/discussion-between-cornifer-and-nick).